# Undefined reference while calling a static constexpr array of variadic types

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following class

```
template<int ... Args>
struct foo {
    constexpr static int arr[sizeof...(Args)]={Args...};
    constexpr int dimension(int i) {return arr[i];}
};
```

But I get `undefined reference to arr`, while calling `dimension`. If I move `arr` inside the function `dimension` then the function cannot be a `constexpr` anymore, because it requires two semicolons within the body of the function. For instance, I cannot do

```
constexpr int a = foo_obj.dimension(2);
```

My goal is to metaprogrammatically iterate over all the dimensions of a varidic template and compare it to another integral number? Ideally if I have two objects of foo I want to determine if they are equal in every dimension.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Can't repro (once I add the missing `int` in `arr` and `;` for `foo`)

Comment: @Barry Fairly sure that you will run into ODR issues once you do a `dimension` call with a run-time value.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question; two specializations of `foo` have the same type iff their `Args...` are the same, so why do you need to do anything beyond `std::is_same`?

Comment: @Barry [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b39246c1fdcd2d0) you can see a minimal example

Comment: Is the question just how to fix that undefined reference?

Comment: @T.C. silly of me. That never occurred to me. Thanks. I still want to have a `dimension`  function though.

Comment: @Barry yes, Is that because of the static keyword in front `arr` that I cannot access it in other member functions?

Comment: Does your interface allow you just to define array inside `dimention`? (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b6204aa24d7d755)

Comment: @Lol4t0 that is only allowed in `c++14`. Although I have recent versions of the compilers, I cant use `c++14` features, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every variable that is odr-used needs a definition. This:

```
constexpr static int arr[sizeof...(Args)]={Args...};
```

is a declaration that also initializes `arr`, but it isn't a definition. So you just have to provide a definition, which must be both (1) external to the class and (2) still `constexpr`. That is:

```
template<int ... Args>
struct foo {
    constexpr static int arr[sizeof...(Args)]={Args...};
    constexpr int dimension(int i) const {return arr[i];}
};

template <int... Args>
constexpr int foo<Args...>::arr[sizeof...(Args)];
```

And now `foo<Args...>::arr` is defined.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a ton for the fix and explanation.